# How to use SQL math functions with multiple joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

in SQL Server I have two fact tables. FactA I will use COUNT(DISTINCT) and need to use two joins to get the needed GROUP BY and WHERE data from DimB. FactB uses SUM and needs only one join to DimB. Now I can make these queries work one by one, but I am at complete lost, trying to merge them into one query.

Here is an extremely simplified example data:

```
    CREATE TABLE FactA
    ([Customer] varchar(3), [Dept] varchar(5))
;
    
INSERT INTO FactA
    ([Customer], [Dept])
VALUES
    ('Aaa', 'DeptA'),
    ('Bbb', 'DeptA'),
    ('Ccc', 'DeptA'),
    ('Ddd', 'DeptB'),
    ('Fff', 'DeptB'),
    ('Aaa', 'DeptC'),
    ('Aaa', 'DeptC')
;

CREATE TABLE DimA
    ([Dept] varchar(5), [Area] varchar(2))
;
    
INSERT INTO DimA
    ([Dept], [Area])
VALUES
    ('DeptA', 'SW'),
    ('DeptB', 'NW'),
    ('DeptC', 'SE')
;


CREATE TABLE DimB
    ([Area] varchar(2), [Code] varchar(2), [PO] varchar(2))
;
    
INSERT INTO DimB
    ([Area], [Code], [PO])
VALUES
    ('SW', 'XA', 'Z1'),
    ('NW', 'XB', 'Z3'),
    ('SE', 'XC', 'Z5')
;


CREATE TABLE FactB
    ([Sales] int, [Code] VARCHAR(2))
;
    
INSERT INTO FactB
    ([Sales], [Code])
VALUES
    (20, 'XA'),
    (10, 'XA'),
    (25, 'XA'),
    (30, 'XB'),
    (40, 'XB'),
    (15, 'XC'),
    (20, 'XC'),
    (35, 'XC')
;
```

Example queries that work by themselves and give expected results are:

```
SELECT DimB.PO,COUNT(DISTINCT FactA.Customer) As Customers
FROM FactA
JOIN DimA ON DimA.Dept = FactA.Dept
Join DimB ON DimB.Area = DimA.Area
GROUP BY DimB.PO

SELECT DimB.PO, sum(FactB.Sales) As TotalSales
FROM FactB
JOIN DimB ON DimB.Code = FactB.Code
GROUP BY DimB.PO
```

I need to combine these two, so I can get the results with one query, and use GROUP BY and WHERE clause from DimB. I tried this:

```
SELECT DimB.PO,COUNT(DISTINCT FactA.Customer) As Customers, SUM(FactB.Sales) As TotalSales
FROM FactA
JOIN DimA ON DimA.Dept = FactA.Dept
Join DimB ON DimB.Area = DimA.Area
Join FactB ON FactB.Code = DimB.Code
GROUP BY DimB.PO
```

And it failed miserably, because it is giving way too large numbers in TotalSales. I believe it is summing way too much sales, because of the many joins. Searching around I belive subqueries might be the answer, but I am overwhelmed about which part I should be subquerying. Many thanks to anyone who has time to help.

Comment: What are the results you expect from the "combined" query? It is not obvious to us because your separate queries are grouping by `DimB.PO` but your combined query is attempting to group by `DimB.Code` instead.

Comment: My apologies, I edited the "combined" query to use DimB.PO, because it is important to be able to use DimB-table for grouping or where clauses.

Comment: Typo aside, it will still be useful for you to show us what results you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to *guess* these are the results you want. Please always state the desired results explicitly so we don't have to guess.

```
;WITH SalesByCode(Code, Sales) AS 
(
  SELECT Code, SUM(Sales) FROM dbo.FactB GROUP BY Code
)
SELECT DimB.PO, 
  Customers  = COUNT(DISTINCT FactA.Customer), 
  TotalSales = MAX(sbc.Sales)
FROM dbo.FactA
JOIN dbo.DimA ON DimA.Dept = FactA.Dept
Join dbo.DimB ON DimB.Area = DimA.Area
Join SalesByCode AS sbc ON DimB.Code = sbc.Code
GROUP BY DimB.PO;
```

Results:

```
PO      Customers    TotalSales 
----    ---------    ----------
Z1              3            55
Z3              2            70
Z5              1            70
```

Comment: You are correct, this is what I needed and I will try to be more clear next time! I'm marking this answer as correct, as I feel it was the most simple way of solving the problem. Thank you for your time and help. The answers by others are also working great, so big thanks to everybody else too!

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE and join them, Please refer below

```
    WITH CUSTOMERS
AS (
    SELECT DimB.PO
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT FactA.Customer) AS Customers
    FROM FactA
    JOIN DimA ON DimA.Dept = FactA.Dept
    JOIN DimB ON DimB.Area = DimA.Area
    GROUP BY DimB.PO
    )
    ,SALES
AS (
    SELECT DimB.PO
        ,sum(FactB.Sales) AS TotalSales
    FROM FactB
    JOIN DimB ON DimB.Code = FactB.Code
    GROUP BY DimB.PO
    )
SELECT CUSTOMERS.PO, CUSTOMERS.Customers, SALES.TotalSales
FROM CUSTOMERS
JOIN SALES ON CUSTOMERS.PO = SALES.PO
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
SELECT
   DimB.PO
  ,sub.CustomerCount
  ,sum(FactB.Sales)  TotalSales
 from FactB
  inner join DimB
   on FactB.Code = DimB.Code
  inner join (--  Get the distinct list of Customers for each Area)
              select
                 DimA.Area
                ,count(distinct FactA.Customer)  CustomerCount
               from DimA
                inner join FactA
                 on FactA.Dept = DimA.Dept
               group by
                DimA.Area)  sub
   on sub.Area = DimB.Area
 group by
   DimB.PO
  ,sub.CustomerCount
```

This allows for different POs that have the same Areas (and, thus, the same customer counts).

Answer (score 1):

If you want counts and sums for all POs from the DimB table, even if they are 0, then you should start from DimB table and then join to subqueries.

```sql
SELECT DimB.PO, 
       ISNULL(a.Customers, 0) AS Customers,
       ISNULL(b.TotalSales, 0) AS TotalSales
FROM DimB
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT DimB.PO,COUNT(DISTINCT FactA.Customer) As Customers
   FROM FactA
   JOIN DimA ON DimA.Dept = FactA.Dept
   Join DimB ON DimB.Area = DimA.Area
   GROUP BY DimB.PO
) AS a ON a.PO = DimB.PO
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT DimB.PO, sum(FactB.Sales) As TotalSales
   FROM FactB
   JOIN DimB ON DimB.Code = FactB.Code
   GROUP BY DimB.PO
) AS b ON b.PO = DimB.PO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select TEMP.*, sum(FactB.Sales) As TotalSales
from (QUERY 1) as TEMP
JOIN DimB on DimB.PO= TEMP.PO
JOIN FactB ON DimB.Code = FactB.Code
GROUP BY DimB.PO
```

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand what I should be writing to (QUERY 1). But the others answers did solve my problem, so no need to explain further, if you don't really feel like it.

Comment: Query 1 is the first select statement you have written

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that, as you are using terms like Fact and Dimension, this is meant to be a Kimball dimensional data model? If that is the case then I think the reason you are struggling to write a query to give the results you want is that your data model is not correctly designed - as one of the main purposes of designing a Kimball data model is to make analytical queries easy, if you find that building the queries you want is difficult then the underlying issue is normally with the data model.

In your example, FactA has no measures (though I guess it could deliberately be a factless fact table?).

You are joining Dimensions to each other which is incorrect, Dimensions should always be related to each other via a Fact table.

If you want to combine measures from multiple fact tables you should query each fact table independently and then union the results using the common conformed dimensions.

Comment: This was actually just a production database running on SQL Server. I renamed the tables and removed lots of unnecessary columns. I'm just used to naming things Facts and Dimensions :-)